# NoReverseMatch Defining keyword arguments in reverse not working

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, arguments

I have two Django views, one that loads a formset and one that submits it. This is to avoid form resubmission or having to change to a different view after POST. And after submit I redirect back to the view that loads the formsets. But I can't get the URLs/reverse to work.

Here are my views and URLs

```
def view(request, model1_id):

    #load formsets

    #pass information to submit view
    request.session['model1_session'] = int(model1_id)

    return render(request, 'app/view.html')

def view_submit(request):
    #get the session
    model1_object = request.session.get('model1_session')
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #save formset
        #error!!!!
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("app:view", kwargs={"model1_id":  "model1_object"}))


url(r'^(?P<model1_id>[0-9]+)/model1/something/$', views.view, name='view' ),
url(r'^model1/something/submit/$', views.view_submit, name='view_submit' ),
```

But when I press submit, everything saves just fine, but the reverse doesn't work....

```
Internal Server Error: /app/model1/something/submit/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Database/project/app/views.py", line 412, in view_submit
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("app:view", kwargs={"model1_id":  "model1_object"}))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 600, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 508, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'model1_id': 'model1_object'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'app/(?P<model1_id>[0-9]+)/model1/something/$']
```

I don't understand why it won't take the kwargs?

```
class Model1(models.Model):

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self.id) or u''

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #I think this is the problem... but I don't know how to solve it...
        return reverse('app:view', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

...Help...

Comment: Error is happening in `reverse("app:view", kwargs={"model1_id":  "model1_object"}`

Comment: I don't see any urls resembling `'app:model1'` name pattern. Please provide your full `urls.py`

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Ah I missed that when trying to simplify my code. Should make mode sense now?

Comment: Also note that your `model1_id` should be a number not a string, because of `[0-9]+` in your url pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the string `"model1_object"` instead of the variable `model1_object`. Try:

```
reverse("app:view", kwargs={"model1_id":  model1_object})
```

Note that you can simplify your code by using the [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut instead of `reverse` and `HttpResponseRedirect`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect("app:view", model1_id=model1_object)
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple... great tip does that work exactly the same? :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, the `redirect` line above is a drop-in replacement for your code.